# Function doesn't run if I put data-dismiss="modal"

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAceptarModal" Text="Aceptar" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnAceptarModal_Click"/>
```

I want to add data-dismiss="modal" in order to close the modal and keep using my web page, but when I add it, the OnClick function btnAceptarModal_Click doesn't execute, without it the function runs perfect.

any suggestion?

EDIT: the function btnAceptarModal_Click is on server-side (c#) (probably unnecessary information).

Comment: Can you show us the html of the button once is rendered on the client?

Comment: What is the reason behind displaying a modal window when btnAceptarModal is clicked? Are you getting a confirmation from the user before posting the form to server?

Comment: Yes is a confirmation from user before do something on data base.

Comment: this is what it shows me on chrome when I open the modal:

<input type="submit" name="btnAceptarModal" value="Aceptar" id="btnAceptarModal" class="btn btn-success">